# Cannot understand sentence mistake?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns, errors

**Until it** can be replaced by a faster, more efficient, and more economical means of transportation, trucks will Cary most of the freight within and through metropolitan areas.

Why is the 'Until **it**' wrong?

Comment: Being picky, but "Cary" should read "carry".

Comment: Because "trucks" is plural and "it" doesn't agree in number.  For example, it is perfectly fine to say "*Until it can be replaced, the Orient Express is the most efficient way to get from Paris to Istanbul*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it refers forwards to "trucks", which are plural, and not  to "freight", singular.

Comment: What can be the correct form of the statement?

Comment: "Until they can be replaced by a faster, more efficient, and more economical means of transportation, trucks will carry most of the freight within and through metropolitan areas."

Comment: I would also drop the 'a' since there may be multiple replacements.

Comment: @Jim. Concur. That was his sentence with his specified correction, not mine. I don't like "means of transportation" and would probably have used something about "transportation systems".